# using col-xs is making link unfunctional in mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, col

I'm facing a very weird issue was unable to understand why this occurs.
All my links work in the desktop version but when i switch to mobile the links no longer seem to work.
This is a live project where i am encountering this issue please have a look at 
http://www.artpandora.com/productView?productId=61
the quick view works in desktop but once i switch to mobile it does not work.The link works when i remove col-xs-* for the div.(But this screws up the UI).

Answer (score 0):

Fix: Adding a clearfix class to the div#section2 fixes the link problem.

When trying to right click > inspect element, you could see that you could not select the good block, but the block under that div element.